# How do I reference angular-latest installed by bower?

Tags: angularjs, bower

I have installed AngularJS using bower, by calling:

```
$ bower install angular-latest
```

Now I wonder how to integrate AngularJS into my html file. Apparently, there is neither an `angular[.min].js` file nor an `index.js` file as suggested by the bower documentation.

I can't imagine that I am the first person on earth to discover this problem, but unfortunately I did not find any clues on this on Google (but perhaps I only used the wrong terms for searching).

Any idea of how to include AngularJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution:

```
$ bower install angular
```

And everything is fine ...

Comment: where did you find angular.js / index.js?

Comment: I don't know any more (and I stepped away from using bower, hence I can not look it up without trying it again).

Comment: @FrankSchwieterman After installing the `angular` package, I found it in `bower_components/angular/angular.min.js`

Comment: thanks.  When I had tried, I had installed the wrong package (bower install angularjs, or something like that) which wasn't actually angular itself.  Anyhow, its correct now.

Answer (score 3):

What you installed with

```
$ bower install angular-latest
```

was only the latest source code. You need to actually build AngularJS.

First, you need to install all of the following dependencies if you haven't already:

- Git
- Node.js
- Java
- Grunt
- Bower

Second, change into the `angular.js` directory.

Then, install node.js dependencies and bower components:

```
$ npm install

$ bower install
```

Finally, you're ready to build your package:

```
$ grunt package
```

In the resulting `build` directory, you'll find

- `angular.js` — The non-minified angular script
- `angular.min.js` — The minified angular script